# Make TabControl Width equal to Max TabItems Width and Height

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

I have a `TabControl` with many `TabItems` inside.
I am trying to make `TabControl's width` equal to Max of its `TabItems Width`(same for Height).
I cannot set it explicitly, because my program is multilanguage, and so depending on language selected, I need different widths to all of my labels(they all are in "auto").

Is there a way to do in only in XAML?

**Edit :**

I found a part of solution in order to do it in the code : When I open my window I do the following :

```
List<TabItem> list = new List<TabItem>();
list.AddRange(tabControl.Items.OfType<TabItem>());
foreach (TabItem tabItem in list)
{
    tabControl.SelectedItem=tabItem;
    tabControl.UpdateLayout();
    tabItem.UpdateLayout();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);
    maxWidth = Math.Max(maxWidth, tabItem.ActualWidth);
    maxHeight = Math.Max(maxHeight, tabItem.ActualHeight);
}
tabControl.Width = maxWidth;
tabControl.Height = maxHeight;
```

It seems to be a working solution, but I don't understand why `tabItem.ActualWidth` and `tabItem.ActualHeight` are always set to 0?

To understand better, I put a screenshot of my window :

[image: options]

When I open my window, I already know in which language it may be opened, so the TabItems dimensions don't change after the windows is loaded.

Edit 2 :

Here is concretely what I mean by "size of TabItems differ regarding used language, this is not the best example as here difference is small, but I would like to apply that to all TabContols of my project to be sure I never met the problem if I make changes in future, or even add another languages :

In Russian :

[image]

In English :

[image]

Comment: How often are there new tab items, and how often do their widths change? A more conventional solution would be to give the TabControl all the space you can, and design the tab item layouts to adjust to the space available.

Comment: I have 5 TabItems, their dimensions don't change while the windows is opened, but they dimensions may differ regarding in which language the software is working. Concretely, when I open the menu "Option", this opens me a new WPF Window, in which there is a TabControl, and each TabItem corresponds to some sections of options (for now General, Nesting, Marking, Drilling, Time management)

Comment: @EdPlunkett I think I found a solution that could fit (see my edit), if U had an idea, thanks.

Comment: I think you'd have to iterate through your items, render them offscreen and check the desired size. Then make the width of current item that width.  Which is why the "usual" approach is to make the tabcontrol big enough for any and make the items cope with "extra" width. And wrap their content in a scrollviewer so they're never cut off.

Comment: @Andy what do you mean by "render them offscreen" ?

Comment: Instantiate a copy in memory. Call measure and arrange on this version. Then check the desired size. But i would  instead make the tabcontrol a fixed size as i suggested above.

Comment: But Measure and Arrange suppose I know what will be its dimension, isn't it? Make a fixed size as I explained, cause the size will depends on which language I am using.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I think I got a valid answer, could you please have a look, would be interesting to have your opinion thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution, maybe not the best, but it is working perfectly, and didn't find any other solution.
It is not possible to do the job when initializing the window, as the contents has not been loaded yet (MyWindow.Show()), so I had to use the SizeChanged event of TabControl.

On my ViewModel I set two parameters `TabControlWidth` and `TabControlHeight`.

```
private double tabControlWidth = 0;
public double TabControlWidth
{
    get { return tabControlWidth; }
    set
    {
        if (this.tabControlWidth != value)
        {
            tabControlWidth = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged("TabControlWidth");
        }
    }
}
private double tabControlHeight = 0;
public double TabControlHeight
{
    get { return tabControlHeight; }
    set
    {
        if (this.tabControlHeight != value)
        {
            tabControlHeight = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged("TabControlHeight");
        }
    }
}
```

in my file MyWindow.xaml.cs I add a bool property to check when I checked all TabItems(obviously, this property is set to false when initializing the window) :

```
bool allTabItemsChecked { get; set; }
```

Finally, I need to add to my TabControl two things :

- Bind Width and Height to my properties in ViewModel.
- Add event SizeChanged

  SizeChanged="TabControlSizeChanged" MinHeight="{Binding TabControlHeight}" MinWidth="{Binding TabControlWidth}"

(excuse me, I don't manage to display the last line as code? often happens after I use "-" or "*")

Finally I make the SizeChanged function as following :

```
private void TabControlSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(this.allTabItemsChecked==false)
    {
        int index = tabControl.SelectedIndex;
        List<TabItem> list = new List<TabItem>();
        list.AddRange(tabControl.Items.OfType<TabItem>());
        if (index < list.Count()-1)
        {
            tabControl.SelectedIndex = index + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            this.allTabItemsChecked = true;
            tabControl.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
        contexte.TabControlWidth = Math.Max(tabControl.ActualWidth, contexte.TabControlWidth);
        contexte.TabControlHeight = Math.Max(tabControl.ActualHeight, contexte.TabControlHeight);

    }
}
```

When we display the window, event is automatically launched.
I will then change TabControl.SelectedIndex to the next TabItem, and update TabControl dimensions to the bigger one.
When I reached the last index, I just set SelectedIndex to 0, then set allTabItemsChecked to true.

Comment: It's roughly what I was playing with. It's not pretty, but if it works it works. I think it's the most robust option you'll find, aside from just using all the space you've got. Personally I'd prefer to keep this out of the viewmodel. I'd much rather write two attached dependency properties and put them on the TabControl itself, then bind them with `{RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}`. I'd also bind those two properties to MinHeight and MinWidth, just in case the layout in one of the tab items might expand in some corner case I forgot to test, due to something being auto-sized.

Comment: @EdPlunkett why out of ViewModel ? maybe a bad habbit from me, but usually only my ViewModel is `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and if I put my properties in my window, I have no choice to make my window `INotifyPropertyChanged` too in order to update binding?

Comment: No, make them dependency properties. Dependency properties have their own notification mechanism. Don't ever implement INPC in a window or control. I'd keep it out of the viewmodel because this is state for a control. If you make a consistent practice of keeping control state out of viewmodels, it pays off. I can't imagine a safer way to violate that principle than your code above, so don't take this as a major issue on this one, but it's a very good principle to stick to as much as reasonably possible.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I don't know what are dependency properties but will look at it thanks. INPC I don't know what it is, but will look about both of them thanks. About your comment on binding to `MinWidth` and `MinHeight`, just understood the purpose of it, and in fact it is better to avoid this problem, even it is not a problem now, in future this could be a problem regarding what I will add.

Comment: INPC is INotifyPropertyChanged in Stackoverflowese. All bindable properties on controls or windows are [dependency properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-properties-overview). Use the `propdp` snippet in Visual Studio to help with all the boilerplate in creating them (type `propdp`, then tab, and tab between the yellow-backgrounded bits as you fill them in).

Comment: ok thanks for it, I will look for a tutorial about dep properties, for now I read one, but couldn't really understand how it works, anyway be sure I'll look at it, thanks again.